# Convert Access dropdown stored as string to index in related table

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

In some access database I have a table with the column, let's say category stored as text (categoryOne, CategoryTwo..)

What I want is a Categories table with (CategoryId, CategoryName)

I'm developing an application in SQL Server. I have to create the model of the application from those access databases. Importing the data with Management Studio works fine for int, datetime, etc.. but not for the Category column that is related to other data.

When I was facing similar problem before (converting a list of categories) I used something like that

```sql
 SELECT
     [CategoryId]
       , (
    CASE
        WHEN [CategoryName] = 'CategoryOne' THEN 1 
        WHEN [CategoryName] = 'CategoryTwo' THEN 2 
        WHEN [CategoryName] = 'CategoryThree' THEN 3 
    END
        ) AS CategoryId
 FROM [dbo].[Categories]
```

But now I have hundres of matches.

Any help?

Comment: There very likely isn't a shortcut here. You need some kind of mechanism to map a string to a number. You can do that in a long case expression or you could create table to handle the mapping.

Comment: How I would do it with a table? I’m not sure if I follow you.

Comment: You would create a table with two columns. One column for the dropdown value and the other column for the desired output. Then you can use a join to find the other value. Either approach requires you to type in values though. There is no alternative.

Comment: Ok. I will have to bite the bullet then. Thank you.

Comment: It may be easier to add a new id column to the referenced table and manually update it there vs. writing all this in TSQL. Also, I believe the maximum number of CASE statements you can have is 255.